# Querying all the tables in a DB

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005. I am having a peculiar need now.

I am having a Database and it in turn have several table(>50). All of these table have **a similar named column with a condition**. I want to query this column across all the tables in the DB.

I am not finding a proper solution in Googling. Please help me.

Thanks a lot in Advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your database schema.

Comment: I just want a consolidated result on querying all the tables on that particular column over a ondition.

Comment: That's not going to be something simple because that's not how databases are supposed to work. If find yourself needing to do this it is a strong sign that your schema is not the best for your needs. Without more info on what that column is and why all the tables have it, it's difficult to provide more help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you?

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

Afterwards, you can loop through all tables and query your column.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kevin's suggestion you do something like this, then execute it's output.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @ColumnName = 'MyColumn'

SELECT 'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM ' + TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables
```

Comment: I think you mean `'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM ' + TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_msforeachtable @command1=N'SELECT ''?'', * from ? WHERE yourcol=''whatever'''
```

Above will run query against every table in selected database, and print tablename + every column in the table for conditions met. If it reaches a table that has an invalid column, it'll just keep going (but print an error message).